# How to use a token created in a secret in another resource?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-kubernetes

I'm trying to create a service account secret in order to populate a secret with the token:

```
resource "kubernetes_service_account" "k8s-api-token" {
  metadata {
    namespace = "${var.whatever_namespace}"
    name = "api-service-account"
  }
  secret {
    name = "api-service-account-secret"
  }
}

resource "kubernetes_secret" "k8s-api-token" {
  metadata {
    namespace = "${var.whatever_namespace}"
    name = "${kubernetes_service_account.k8s-api-token.metadata.0.name}-secret"
    annotations = {
      "kubernetes.io/service-account.name" = "${kubernetes_service_account.k8s-api-token.metadata.0.name}"
    }
  }
  type = "kubernetes.io/service-account-token"
}

data "kubernetes_secret" "k8s-api-token" {
  depends_on = ["kubernetes_secret.k8s-api-token"]
  metadata {
    namespace = "${var.whatever_namespace}"
    name = "${kubernetes_secret.k8s-api-token.metadata.0.name}"
  }
}

resource "kubernetes_secret" "whatever-secrets" {
  depends_on = ["kubernetes_secret.k8s-api-token"]
  metadata {
    name = "botfront-secrets"
    namespace = "${var.whatever_namespace}"
  }

  data = {
    K8S_API   = "${data.kubernetes_secret.k8s-api-token.data.token}"
  }
}
```

But it gives me an error:
`Resource 'data.kubernetes_secret.k8s-api-token' does not have attribute 'data.token' for variable 'data.kubernetes_secret.k8s-api-token.data.token'`

I can verify the secret is created, but even running `terraform state show kubernetes_secret.k8s_api_token` doesn't return anything

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you remove the `kubernetes_secret.api-secrets` resource does it actually output? Or is the output empty?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I just have `unknown resource 'kubernetes_secret.api-secrets' referenced in variable kubernetes_secret.api.data.token`

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I edited my question to describe better what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Can you confirm that you are using Terraform 0.11 here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use a lookup:

```
K8S_API = ${lookup(data.kubernetes_secret.k8s-api-token-data.data, "token","")}
```

Source: http://blog.crashtest-security.com/resource-does-not-have-attribute